# How can I extract all first value in a column from other column?

Tags: python

I got a table like this:

```
house
house
house
dog
dog
dog
```

And I would like to have only first occurrence of each different words. So I would like to have a column like this:

```
house     house
house
house
dog       dog
dog
dog
```

Comment: Yes I tried a loop to get every first elements but it still not works

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a dataframe, you can use:

```
df.column_name.unique()
```

if it is a numpy array:

```
np.unique(array)
```

If it is a list:

```
unique = list(set(data))
```

If you don't have the full data and it depends on anything else, you can use a function like:

```
   # initialize a null list
   unique_list = []
 
    # traverse for all elements
   for x in data: # read the data 
         # check if exists in unique_list or not
       if x not in unique_list:
           unique_list.append(x)
```

Comment: thanks ! but it is not data frame :/

Comment: What is the type of your data?

Comment: I just try to do it with a loop if it is possible, because in my software, I can't use function you gave me

Comment: I've just updated the answer for list and array. However, the type of your data and question is not clear yet.

Comment: I just tried to do a code with loop, like for i in 1:N, if ...